# Adding Strings in KDB+

Tags: string, kdb

I am new to KDB+ and q and want to know how I would go about adding two strings to make a sentence.

For example how would I join `w1:"Hello"` to `w2:"World"` to make the new string `"Hello World"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So there are two ways you could go about doing it. The first is to use the join operator (`,`), like so

```
w1 , " " , w2
```

or you could use the scalar-from-vector function (`sv`), like so

```
" " sv (w1; w2)
```

If you want to learn a bit more about kdb+/q, then [Q for Mortals](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/) is a great reference.

Answer (score 0):

" " sv (w1;w2) should work [sv](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/sv/)